# Parent Activity crashes when pressed Action Bar Home Arrow Button from Child Activity while it is ok when pressed Back Button

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, transparency

Parent Activity crashes when pressed Action Bar Home Arrow Button from Child Activity while it is ok when pressed Back Button.

Parent activity receives an intent extra from the Launcher Activity and with that object it sets up its views. Then it starts a Child Activity for result and when the child activity calls finish or back button is pressed from navigator it does not crash the parent activity however when i press the action bar arrow(R.id.home) icon the parent activity crashes with a NullPointerException for mSomeObjectWhichHasANameProperty. How can i avoid this.

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Object mSomeObjectWhichHasANameProperty;
    TextView mNameView;
    Button mSomeButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
        mSomeObjectWhichHasANameProperty=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("object_key");
        mNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mNameView.setText(mSomeObjectWhichHasANameProperty.getName());
        mSomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mSomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ChildActivity.start(this, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
    }
}


public class ChildActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public static void start(Activity context, int requestCode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChildActivity.class);
        context.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    }
    Button mSomeButton;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState {
        mSomeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mSomeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setResult(1);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add crash log

Comment: Actually i simplified the example, but the scenario is same it is giving a NullPointerException for that object.

Comment: I am thinking it is going like this. When i press that 'Back Arrow' icon on Action Bar it does not go back to the parent activity but actually re-creates it  as it is mentioned in the Manifest by its parent activity name and simply calls startActivity and therefore does not set the Parcelabel Object via Intent . And when the parent activity calls a method on that object it crashes giving NullPointerException.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest in ChildActivity:

```
android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivity"
```

Comment: Its added. Please go through it again. When i press the back button on 
 On-Bar Navigation or calls finish from Child Activity it does not crash but when i press that arrow icon on action bar which is also refers to as Menu Option(R.id.home) it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this line of code could be run: `ChildActivity.start(this, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);`

It should be `this.startActivityForResult(Intent, RequestCode)`